# Updating Access 2010 Table from Excel VBA Only updates only one record

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Having quite a time trying to update an access table from excel.  I am using ADOB Connection and looping through spreadsheet that has the updates.  This can be anywhere from 200 records to 1000 + records.

When running the following code It will only update one record in the access table despite showing it has updated 1047 records from my test data.

I am updating a sales record that has 62 columns. The Column "BI" is the unique ID generated upon quoting.  What the update is specifying is to change Data in the QorB Column from Q to B based upon the ID in Column "BI" (sQID)

After the module runs it shows that it has updated 1047 records from this but when opening the access DB it shows only one record changed.. I am at a loss.

Can anyone see anything drastically wrong with the below code?  is there a better way to update access with a large amount of data from excel?

```
Sub updatedbtest2()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rng As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngID, LR, Upd
Dim sSQL As String

'Get Last Row of range used 
LR = Range("BI" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Upd = LR - 1   
lngRow = 2    
Do While lngRow <= LR
lngID = Cells(lngRow, 61).Value   

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Database\sales.accdb;"

sQID = Cells(2, 61).Value

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

       sSQL = "SELECT * FROM P&R WHERE QuoteID ='" & sQID & "';"  

rs.Open Source:=sSQL, ActiveConnection:=cn, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

        ' update fields within table with values from spreadsheet.
        With rs
            .Fields("QorB") = Cells(lngRow, 60).Value
            .Fields("BDate") = Cells(lngRow, 62).Value
            .update
        End With        
    rs.update   
   'Next rng

lngRow = lngRow + 1

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing       


Loop

MsgBox "You just updated " & Upd & " records"
End Sub
```

Thanks For taking a look at this.

I have made the following changes to the code from suggestions with the same exact results.

[Snip of Access showing records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrTzs.jpg)

```
Sub updatedbtest2()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rng As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim sQID, LR
Dim sSQL As String

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print LR


Upd = LR - 1
lngRow = 2
sQID = Cells(lngRow, 61).Value

'Do While lngRow <= LR

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Database\sales.accdb;"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

       sSQL = "SELECT * FROM PandR WHERE QID ='" & sQID & "';"

    rs.Open Source:=sSQL, ActiveConnection:=cn, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

        Do While lngRow <= LR

        With rs
            .Fields("QorB") = Cells(lngRow, 60).Value
            .Fields("BDate") = Cells(lngRow, 62).Value
            .update

        End With

    'Next rng
    lngRow = lngRow + 1       

    Loop    

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: is it literally only showing one changed record? or is just saying 1 record was changed because you literally open and close the database on each iteration (which is not necessary and probably slowing down your code)? And isn't there a way to write a `UPDATE QUERY` with a join on the ID column from you excel data within ADODB? Would be simpler then looping through thousands of rows, I think.

Comment: It shows in the messagebox 1047 records updated.  When I go to the access table and verify the first record is the only one that has updated the values.

Comment: I see your problem now, I think: this line `sQID = Cells(2, 61).Value` should be `sQID = Cells(lngRow, 61).Value`. Right now it's setting the same `sQID` on each loop, which is why the first record is the only one updated. This also seems superfluous: `lngID = Cells(lngRow, 61).Value ` and the `Upd ` variable is never set with any value, so I would think your `Msgbox` would return only `You just updated  records`

Comment: Yes as well as using debug.print to verify that it was iterating through each row on the spreadsheet and showing the values that was to be updated.

Comment: From your last comment its not clear that you actually see where your problem is. Did you get it?

Comment: when you made the edits, you didn't quite put things in the right place. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're hard-coding this line: `sQID = Cells(2, 61).Value

You should replace this with:

```
sQID = Cells(lngRow, 61).Value
```

Then it will take the value from the next row as opposed to keep picking up the same one.

UPDATE: Scott Holzman got there first!

Answer (score 0):

This code should work as you expect:

```
Sub updatedbtest2()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rng As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim sQID, LR
Dim sSQL As String

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'Debug.Print LR

'Upd = LR - 1
lngRow = 2

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Database\sales.accdb;"

Do While lngRow <= LR

    sQID = Cells(lngRow, 61).Value

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM PandR WHERE QID ='" & sQID & "';"

    With rs
        .Open Source:=sSQL, ActiveConnection:=cn, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

        .Fields("QorB") = Cells(lngRow, 60).Value
        .Fields("BDate") = Cells(lngRow, 62).Value

        .Update

    End With

    'Next rng
    lngRow = lngRow + 1

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

Loop

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```